# HttpServletReponse.sendRedirect using Proxy

Tags: java, azure, tomcat

I am implementing a authentication filter which uses azure ad. If the user is not authenticated he gets redirect to azure ad 'login.microsoft.com'. At this point I get an UnknownHostException since the application server is behind a proxy. So my question is how do I configure a proxy for redirects or for all tomcat apps in general?

I added proxyName and proxyPort to the Connector in the server.xml and now the redirect works but the currentURI of the httpServletRequest is set to:

```
http://http://<proxyHost>:<proxyPort>:<serverPort>/MYAPP
```

Comment: Do you mean apache proxy?

Comment: Turns out the catalina.bat thing was fine, the proxy only supported https. I spend 2 hours debugging - end my suffering